# Get manifest file for a 3rd party app

Tags: android, android-manifest

This [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer&hl=en) allows you to browse applications' manifest files. How does it do that? I can't find anything in the OS's API for getting another application's manifest file.

Answer (score 7):

First, you can get a list of Applications like so:

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA | PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES
    );
```

Then the location of the APK can be gotten from:

```
apps.get(x).publicSourceDir
```

The above will have a value such as:

```
/data/app/com.example.someonesapp.apk
```

From there the manifest file can be accessed from the .apk like so:

```
try {
    ZipFile apk = new ZipFile("/data/app/com.example.someonesapp.apk");
    ZipEntry manifest = apk.getEntry("AndroidManifest.xml");
    if (manifest != null){
        Log.d("ManifestGetter", "Manifest size = " + manifest.getSize());
        InputStream stream = apk.getInputStream(manifest);
        // do stuff with the file here e.g. get contents
        stream.close();
    }
    apk.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Best of all, root is not required

Comment: wow. can't believe Android allows this. what would it be needed for?

Comment: There are some aspects of an app that cannot be queried by another app using the regular API. For example, you cannot through the API directly find out what intents an application supports. However, you can do this by reading its manifest. So then you can trigger some of its public intents.

Comment: I presume if it were a security risk, Google would have plugged it up a long time ago. I suppose while the String value of private intents will be exposed, the main thing is they can't be triggered by anything besides the owning application. What I want to know though, is how to hide my source! Obfuscation is probably all that can ever be expected, whether or not APKs are accessible by other apps, since any user can access APKs on their phone some how anyway.

Comment: Isn't there any android object/service that allows you to parse that? maybe the packagemanager exposes some APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The Manifest file is not hidden when you build you app. It's shipped inside your .apk file as-is. You can check this with an archiver, like 7zip. So just open your apk file with 7zip (it will recognize it) and you will see your AndroidManifest.xml file there.

That app, i assume, just looks for that file in the application folder.