# Get manifest file for a 3rd party app whose base.apk was deleted

Tags: android

My question is the same posted [Get manifest file for a 3rd party app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473904/get-manifest-file-for-a-3rd-party-app), but the answer is really tricky and it doesn't work in such case. 
It's really strange that there isn't some API that provides an easy way to parse the manifest of 3rd party apps.
Moreover afaik the base.apk can be deleted, so is there another way to read the manifest of an app whose base.apk was deleted?

For the sake of clarity: whenever you install an app, you can find a file named base.apk in /data/app/packagename/base.apk which is the original apk downloaded from the market

Comment: How do you want to read manifest if apk is deleted? Manifest is inside apk.

Comment: I'm talking about the base.apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PackageManager` to get most of the information about installed applications. You can't get everything that is in the manifest, but you can get most of the interesting bits. As long as the app is installed on the device, you can get information from the `PackageManager`.